# ERROR: Only variable references should be returned by reference in wp-includes/post.php

Tags: wordpress, php

I keep getting this error when I put PHP error reporting on in my **WordPress** setup.

`Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference in /Users/admin/Sites/wp-includes/post.php on line 3394`

I have a feeling it has to do with the **taxonomies and their hierarchal setup**.

Been trying to track it down for a while now **in the plugin I'm writing**.

These are the actual lines of code in the WP Core, the return being on the excact line.

```
 // Make sure the post type is hierarchical
 $hierarchical_post_types = get_post_types( array( 'hierarchical' => true ) );
 if ( !in_array( $post_type, $hierarchical_post_types ) )
      return false;
```

I'll keep debugging it till I find the issue, but any input would be great seeing that i've not tracked down the issue in my plugin.

Comment: Maybe your plugin is calling a WP core function wrong and causing the error (have it sometimes with jQuery). Look at the backtrace to find out what the function is that is called before the WP core function. You can use `debug_print_backtrace()`;  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return false;` - that's not a variable
Try something like

```
if ( !in_array( $post_type, $hierarchical_post_types ) ) {
      $rv = false;
      return $rv;
}
```

(side-note: I have no idea what wordpress and/or a mod you're using there is doing, but maybe/probably "return by reference" is a) unnecessary in the first place and b) a relict from a php4 implementation)

Comment: Nice work. This actually remedied the problem. But it sits in the WP Core so will have to log a ticket I guess. Strange because it's the default vanilla get_pages() function that's throwing this error (since V.1.5.0). Perhaps a PHP 5.4 issue.

Comment: And it seems to only throw the notice error from my plugin and not if it's in the theme...

Comment: Issue is in the Trac, will keep an eye on it. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20756#comment:2